# How to enable RowTest in MSTest for VS2012

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

guys, I found that there is no such  RowTest in MSTest, So how can I enable this functionary? Thanks!

Comment: yes,I see this question,but seem like the link which memtioned in the answer is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this blog post, which extends the unit test type to include tests on rows.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/09/04/extending-the-visual-studio-unit-test-type-part-2.aspx